# What's the POS framework call corresponding to StartSoftwareTriggerAsync application API call?

Tags: windows, barcode-scanner, umdf

I am working on barcode scanner project on windows 10 and we are going to use software triggering. I got the mentioned APIs from application to implement software triggering but couldn't get information on the driver side handler for these calls?

Can someone suggest what would be the corresponding POS framework call for this software trigger API?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Tajpeer

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer in your question contents.

Please describe what you want to do and what you are going to do concretely.

For example, I guessed what you want to do as follows.

1. Acquire images in real time from the camera connected to the PC and keep displaying it in the window of the PC screen.
2. Hold the barcode in the reading area of ​​the camera, human confirms that it was displayed cleanly in the window, and performs barcode recognition by software trigger via POS application.
3. When the program can recognize the bar code, notify it to the POS application.

There are no such functions or APIs in the existing POS framework (UnifiedPOS (OPOS / POS for .NET / JavaPOS), Windows.Devices.PointOfService).

As an alternative, the closest one is to implement UnifiedPOS ImageScanner and Scanner (Bar Code Reader) as a Hydra device on one camera.
The software trigger function is implemented as a vendor specific extension function by the DirectIO method.